# Show label for each bar in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can I show labels for each bar in Highcharts as shown in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to have grouped x-Axis labels??

Comment: Add some code what you have done. Starting sample might be https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic. This is not code writing service check [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks that you should be able to use grouped-categories plugin for making your chart: https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking is some thing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wLx59g8e/).

This canbe achieved using the datalabels and placing them properly at the position you have desired to.

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          y: 0,
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          inside: true,
          color: 'white',
          formatter: function(e) {
            return this.series.name
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `overflow` to 'none' and `crop` to false to be able to display data labels out of the area plot.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5m0kkbhf/